# Detecting/redirecting output of all terminal commands

Tags: bash, unix

How to do this with a Unix shell?

```
$ startRedirecting.sh
$ ls
abc.txt def.txt
$ pwd
/home/bob/demo
$ stopRedirecting.sh
$ cat /someDir/someOutput.txt
abc.txt def.txt
/home/bob/demo
```

How to write `startRedirecting.sh` that makes sure that the output of each of the following commands is redirected to `/someDir/someOutput.txt`

Ruby/python scripts would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want the output redirected, but tee'd to both your terminal and a log file. Have you tried simply using [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)?

Answer (score 2):

@Celada's answer is the best. It seems odd to have a log file of output without also logging the commands that produced the output.

However, you can achieve your specific request:

```
$ exec 3>&1
$ exec > >(tee output.log)
$ pwd
/home/jackman
$ whoami
jackman
$ exec >&3
$ cat output.log 
/home/jackman
jackman
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to redirect the output of a series of command to a file, then "turn off" the redirection afterwards, you can try this

```
$ exec >file
$ ls
$ pwd
$ exec >/dev/stdout
```

Notes:

- `exec >file`: redirect STDOUT to file for all the commands that follows
- `exec >/dev/stdout`: redirect STDOUT back to STDOUT for all the commands that follows